# Select specific row multiple values with same id

Tags: mysql, row

I have the following data in MySQL table package_in_plan

```
+------------+----------+------+
| package_id | plan_id  | opt  |
+------------+----------+------+
|  4         | 9        |    0 |
|  35        | 9        |    0 |
|  8         | 9        |    0 |
|  8         | 4        |    0 |
|  4         | 4        |    0 |
|  4         | 16       |    0 |
|  5         | 15       |    0 |
+------------+----------+------+
```

I want to be able to Select package_id 4 and 8 
and the output should be plan_id 4 ONLY. I don't want it to output plan_id 9 because plan_id 9 has package_id 35 which plan_id 4 doesn't so i want it to be specific that these package_id requested are same to the plan_id.

This is my SQL that i have come to so far, and stuck from there.

```
Select * from package_in_plan where package_id in(4,8) group by plan_id having count(*) >1;
```

And of course this one is not working. Appreciate the help.

Comment: you are close, it should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT package_id) = 2` since you are only looking for 2 packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Select *
from package_in_plan
where package_id in(4,8)
  AND plan_id NOT IN (SELECT plan_id FROM package_in_plan where package_id not in (4,8))
```

Get all the data with package_id like 8 or 4 and ignores those having plan_id with package_id unlike 8 or 4.

If u can pass another variable to the query make like @John Woo said

```
Select *
from package_in_plan
where package_id in(4,8)
group by plan_id
having COUNT(distinct package_id) = @num (how many packages you want)
```

Comment: Perfect! Working like a charm. Appreciate the help, one more question if possible. For example lets say i now want to search for package_id in(4,8,35) how can i output only 9, and ignore the 4. This answer is giving me both 9&4. If 4,8,35 is used.